# Is HttpUnit deprecated / inactive / not supported?

Tags: http-unit

When I explored and worked on HttpUnit 3 yrs back I liked it for what it does. Though after 3 yrs of not tracking it, when I suggested a solution based on it to my colleague, he told me it is deprecated? The apache status tells it is active. No where I could find if this is true. I will be shocked if that is true. Went thro the bug list and found no assignees for last 1 year. Should I conclude from this inference that it is deprecated?

Comment: can you give link of http-unit or the bug list from apache? or you talking about http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/?

Comment: yes. i am talking about sourceforge.

Comment: last release was on 20 May 2008 that's quite a long time

Answer (score 4):

My name is Wolfgang Fahl and I am one of the committers of httpunit.

The project is not dead. Russell and me still commit changes regularly. Progress is slow since there are not too many developers involved. You are kindly invited to participate if you'd like to see any improvements.  We have just released 1.7.2 to maven.org a few weeks ago:

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.httpunit|httpunit|1.7.2|jar

See 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705675/patch-process-for-httpunit/21706183#21706183
for an ongoing activity. Please feel free to ask more questions here.

Comment: Hello Wolfgang, than at least the startpage of httpunit is misleading as the last news entry is from May 2008. I found this thread by looking for `httpunit dead`, so maybe you should at least actualize the frontpage's news-section when doing a new release.

Answer (score 4):

The news has not been updated because the website has not been updated, and is no longer current with the changes to sourceforge. I am looking into moving the project to github.

Comment: Yes it is; I have moved the source code to github now; https://github.com/russgold/httpunit

I have a bit of work to get the website over as well; releases are now being done via Maven Central.