# Patch process for httpunit

Tags: http-unit

I would like to know the currently practiced procedure in patching httpunit.

I saw in this thread
[Is HttpUnit deprecated / inactive / not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630395/is-httpunit-deprecated-inactive-not-supported)
that Russell has put the httpunit source to his github repo.

The FAQ note for httpunit still talks about the svn repo at sourceforge for patching.

If I have a patch, should I use the svn repo and attach the patch to the ticket to source forge's issue tracking or use the repo at github and send a pull request there?

Thanks.
Regards, aki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My name is Wolfgang Fahl and I am one of the committers of httpunit. Thank you for pointing out that the FAQ is outdated regarding the usage of subversion - I am going to fix the FAQ.

The pull request approach seems like a reasonable way to proceed. You might want to make sure that you add

- a Junit Test - that shows your change is necessary
  -- the test should fail before the change and all other tests should succeed
  -- the test should succeed after the change and all other tests should succeed
- and the change in the source code

To get the current source code of httpunit you may clone it via:

`git clone https://github.com/russgold/httpunit`

if you do a

`mvn test`

the result should like

> Results :
>   Tests run: 822, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 8

With 822/8 being the number of tests as of 2014-02-11 that are executed/skipped.
The Failures should be 0.

Please feel free to add a link to your patch / your pull request here. I appreciate that you are using stackoverflow as a platform for this communication and I hope more of the httpunit users and developers will do so in the future.

Comment: Hi Wolfgang, thanks. I created a pull request https://github.com/russgold/httpunit/pull/1 thanks. aki

Comment: Thanks. I did a:

git pull https://github.com/elakito/httpunit master

mvn test

Tests run: 823, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 8

git push

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a very good approach; I have to do some work to update the website to reflect it.