# Setting up a dynamic web project with maven and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I am setting up a web project with maven and eclipse

I followed the steps given here 
[Java Dynamic Web project with Maven and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888068/java-dynamic-web-project-with-maven-and-eclipse)

Now in my eclipse IDE I have a web project with the maven directory structure, I have installed m2e plugin. On doing right click on the project I see a maven option.

Now I am a little confused. How do I clean build and run the project? In the tutorials on 
the net I see a black command prompt where developers run some commands. Is something else to be done?. Do I have to install
maven in my windows system? Won't I be able to do all the process from within eclipse?

Comment: Read this: http://www.tech-juice.org/2012/05/13/hello-world-with-jsf-2-0-glassfish-3-maven-svn-and-eclipse/#Install_Eclipse_Plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I clean build and run the project?

You will find on the option here
*right-click on the project --> Run as --> Maven clean/build/install*

1. Maven Clean will fire the *mvn clean* command
2. Maven Install will fire the *mvn install*
3. Maven Build . Thats just a generic interface to define custom goals
   and properties for a new maven build configuration.

> In the tutorials on the net I see a black command prompt where developers run some commands. Is something else to be done?. Do I have to install maven in my windows system?

That is completely your choice, if you are comfortable with using the maven from command prompt then yes you will have to install maven in your operating system also. Otherwise if you just going to use maven from within eclipse, then you don't have to set it up on your OS at all

> Won't I be able to do all the process from within eclipse?

Yes you can, but sometimes some other commands have to be used besides clean/install , like the deploy command, or any-other , for that, take a look into the Maven Build option. You can make custom configurations here from within eclipse and fire any maven command with arguments as you like.

Answer (score 0):

you can also run from eclipse `your project> Run as>maven>clean` or build or install.

for this you need to configure you eclipse to have maven in it.

if you have maven installed in your directory.

then in eclipse

`windows>preference>maven>Installation>` add your maven directory here.

after this you dont need to clean build project through command prompt , you can do in your eclipse.