# Unit testing of Servlets

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets

I need to write unit test around a function which takes HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse object as an argument.

If I create the mock of these two object(request and response), how change in one will reflect in another.

Ex. If I want to unit test around the code where I am setting the header in response object.

```
response.addHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=EmulateIE7");
```

Let me know how to proceed .

Comment: Try using one of the frameworks defined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/91109/245679). This will make your life easier.

Comment: Have you seen this : http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/servletunit-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

In your mocking library there will be some way to assert that a method has been invoked. So, your test code would include a statement such as:

```
// psuedo-code
assertThat(mockResponse).addHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=EmulateIE7");
```

In the mocking frameworks I have used (JMock, Mockito), there is no automatic co-operation between mocked objects. So your mocked `HttpServletRequest` will have no relationship to your mocked `HttpServletResponse` unless you declare one.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Framework provides both a [`MockHttpServletRequest`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/index.html?org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html) and a [`MockHttpServletResponse`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletResponse.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with standard mocks, they will create you a proxy. So you may never know if the correct value was set after the code calls

response.addHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=EmulateIE7");

If you create the stub yourself then you can actually verify what was set in the method call. But this approach has many problems as well.