# Testing: is there a framework allowing embedding Tomcat to simulate request/response cycles without involving HTTP?

Tags: java, unit-testing, tomcat, jetty

For automated functional testing purposes, I would like to run a servlet container from my test driver without actually issuing HTTP requests over the network. The main goal is to test fairly elaborate conditions of servlet filtering, forwarding, and includes.

I would like a system that embeds the servlet container in a way that:

- doesn't create a separate process if possible
- doesn't cause the embedded container to listen on network ports
- allows me to issue simulated HTTP requests (through an API)
- allows me to wait for/receive responses and analyze them from Java code

I know that Tomcat can be embedded [through an API](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Embedded.html) and has a connector API, so I am sure that it is doable. But surely there must exist a test framework out there doing exactly this already?

(Note that I would prefer if Tomcat is used, but Jetty is another option.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit-testing servlets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532/unit-testing-servlets)

Answer (score 2):

What about using [Jakarta Cactus](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/)? Check out [How it works](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/how_it_works.html) and the [TestCase Howto](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/writing/howto_testcase.html) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks I am evaluating it and will see if it meets the needs.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, it seems that Cactus still relies on using HTTP to connect to the container, so it is not ideal from that perspective.

Comment: Hmmm... Cactus has a ServletTestCase (and JspTestCase and FilterTestCase) and WebRequest and WebResponse classes for Servlet unit testing (in the junit sense). See http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/writing/howto_testcase_servlet.html and http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/how_it_works.html. Pay a special attention to the *Redirector Proxies* section.

Comment: "2011/08/05 - Jakarta Cactus has been retired."