# How to do Unittests in Servlet-Applet scenario

Tags: java, servlets, applet, unit-testing

How should I create & run unit-tests for a Java/Tomcat Servlet-Applet application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit-testing servlets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532/unit-testing-servlets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jakarta cactus](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/) is a unit-testing framework for servlets.