# Servlet unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, testng, mockrunner

Currently I'm using TestNG framework for testing application business logic, i added some Servlet classes recently.

How do I unit test these Servlet classes in TestNg framework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit-testing servlets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532/unit-testing-servlets)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow skaffman's advice if possible. If not, or if you want to test the behaviour of the servlets as front-end controllers, rather than the business logic inside them, you can use:

- [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)
- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)
- [Cactus](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/) (but I don't know how whether it supports TestNG already)

Comment: Thanks Bozho, does Selenium support TestNG?

Comment: Yes, Selenium supports TestNG.  I would only use it though if you need tests to run in parallel. If not, stick with JUnit.

Answer (score 18):

One of the easiest ways is [ServletTester](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/ServletTester) from Jetty. Everything is done within embedded Jetty automatically, so there is no port opened during the testing! If you use Maven than the following artifact is required to enable this method:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-servlet-tester</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.16</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Example:

Prepare ServletTester

```
ServletTester tester=new ServletTester(); 
tester.addServlet(HelloServlet.class, "/hello"); 
tester.start();
```

Create HTTP request

```
HttpTester request = new HttpTester(); 
request.setMethod("GET");
request.setHeader("Host","tester"); 
request.setURI("/hello");
request.setVersion("HTTP/1.0");
```

Call servlet and retrieve response:

```
HttpTester response = new HttpTester();
response.parse(tester.getResponses(request.generate()));
```

Assert what you want to check on response and it's content:

```
assertEquals(200,response.getStatus()); 
assertEquals("Hello Servlet",response.getContent());
```

Comment: @koppernickus: Can I integrate this test class with TestNG?

Comment: @Thomman: Yes. This class is independent of any Test Framework.

Comment: Interesting.  Other servlet testers require a port, etc.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest that you move all of the business logic *out* of the servlet classes, into your own classes which you can test. That leaves the servlets just as glue between your business logic and the container, with nothing in them worth testing.

The API classes such as `HttpServletRequest`, `ServletConfig`, etc, are prime targets for using a mocking framework of your choice (JMock, Mockito, etc), since they're all interfaces.

Comment: Thanks Skaffman, my servlets handle session and cookie related operation. So moving these logics to another class is not possible. I'm looking an API which allows me unit test servlet within testNG.

Comment: @Thomman: It's always possible - just delegate from the servlet to the  business logic class. There's nothing that *has* to go in the servlet.

Comment: There can still be aneed to test at the servlet level, although that would be integration testing rather than unit testing.