# JUnit - Run test cases from a web application

Tags: java, servlets, junit, junit4

I have a set of test cases that are written in `JUnit`. Since there is a dependency on the servlet container for these test cases, I want to run them from a `servlet`. For example, if I pass the fully qualified class name of the Test class to the servlet, it should be able to run that test case.
I have these test cases in the class path of web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * The various JUNIT classes should be passed as the <code>class</code> request paramter in the URL.
 * @param request
 * @param response
 */
private void executeJUNITTestCases( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ){
    response.setContentType( "text/plain" );
    //Pass the class names of the Test cases in the URL parameter "class"
    String[] className = request.getParameterValues( "class" );
    try{
        if( className = null || className.length == 0){
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put( "error", "Class names should be provided as parameter values of key [class]" );
            writer.write( obj.toString() );
            return;
        }

        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        final PrintStream pout = new PrintStream( out );
        new JUnitCore().runMain( new JUnitSystem(){

            public PrintStream out(){
                return pout;
            }

            public void exit( int arg0 ){}
        }, className );
        out.close();
    }
    catch( IOException e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Above code helps us to invoke the JUnit test cases within the web application context.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you require a servlet container but usually it is better to mock the environment so that you are in control and can simulate different cases.

Within the following document [Unit testing of servlet using mock framework (MOCKITO)](https://javakapil.wordpress.com/2012/04/29/unit-testing-of-servlet-using-mock-framework-mockito/) is explained how to unit test servlets using mockito, and this question can also be of interest [How to test my servlet using JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434419/how-to-test-my-servlet-using-junit).

Comment: Mocking the environment may not be enough in cases where we have to test transactions where multiple resources are involved.