# How do I write JUnit test case for Servlets

Tags: servlets, junit

My servlet checks the entered username and password. For ex: If username is null then I am setting error in the request i.e request.setAttribute(). If credentials are valid then I forward the request to welcome page. How do I write test cases for RequestDispatcher and request.setAttribute() methods.

Comment: check this post, it can be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434419/how-to-test-my-servlet-using-junit

Comment: Got it. I can just use verify(request,atLeast(1)).getParameter("username");