# How to test mvc controller method with http response argument?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

Can you help me? I need to test this controller method. But don't know what to do with httpservletresponse object.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @PostMapping("/signout")
    public String signOut(HttpServletResponse response){
        response.addCookie(new Cookie("auth-token", null));
        return "redirect:http://localhost:3000";
    }
}
```

Thank you)

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434419/how-to-test-my-servlet-using-junit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spring MVC Test** provides an effective way to test controllers by performing requests and generating responses through the actual DispatcherServlet.

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers=HomeController.class)
public class HomeControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Test
    public void testSignOut() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(post("/signout"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(new ResultMatcher() {                
                @Override
                public void match(MvcResult result) throws Exception {              
                    Assert.assertEquals("http://localhost:3000",result.getResponse().getRedirectedUrl());
                }
            });

    }

}
```

In case of **Spring MVC** without spring boot, use standalone MockMvc support

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration // or @ContextConfiguration
public class HomeControllerTest{

    @Autowired
    private HomeController homeController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        // Setup Spring test in standalone mode
        this.mockMvc = 
          MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(homeController).build();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, But the problem is httpservletresponse. I don't know how to pass it)

Comment: I have mocked response and I need to pass it and check if method addCookie was invoked

Comment: You can do response.getCookies and verify the response. You could also use Mockito.verify to check addCookie was called.