# Need to use Unit testing famework for testing J2EE Components like Servlets , Filters and JPA

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, junit, servlet-filters

I need to create unit tests for J2EE components like Servlets, Filters and JPA code which would call it's life cycle methods automatically and would integrate with Maven2 and Continuum and can be run from IDE itself.

Can you suggest something?

Thanks,
Vaibhav

Comment: For Servlets, see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532/unit-testing-servlets

Answer (score 2):

- for servlets you can use [Jakarta Cactus](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/)
- for database testing you can use [unitils](http://www.unitils.org/summary.html) or [DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/)

Also, you can use a mocking framework like [mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) or JMockIt