# Webservice functional/integration test with Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, integration-testing, fail-fast

The question aims to find a better solution than mine.

I have the following **REQUIREMENTS** for my integration tests:

1. Each integration test is implemented in a single test class.
2. The methods in a test class have to be executed in order.
3. Each method is one step of the integration/functional test.
4. If a test method fails all other test methods in the test class have to be skipped - because it does not make sense to find subsequent errors.

**MY SOLUTION** looks like this:

I just inherit every test class from my abstract test class:

```
package myPackage;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;

public abstract class FailFastTest {

    private final static List<Class<?>> FAILED_CLASSES = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Class<?>>() ;

    private final Class<? extends FailFastTest> thatClass = this.getClass();

    @Rule
    public final TestWatcher onFailedRule = new TestWatcher() {
        protected void failed(Throwable e, org.junit.runner.Description description) {
            FAILED_CLASSES.add(thatClass);
        };
    };

    @Before
    public final void beforeMethod() {
        final boolean failed = FAILED_CLASSES.contains(thatClass);

        if(failed) {
            System.out.println(thatClass + " FAILED. Aborting test.");
            org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(!failed);
        }
     }
}
```

Does anybody have a better idea?
My **PROBLEM**:
I cannot run such a test class multiple times in parallel because of the classname signals the skipping...

***NO! It is not a duplicate!***
I try to write functional tests which use different (web-)services in a specific order. The Question "How do I test a servlet?" is quite different!

Anyway. I switched to TestNG. TestNG supports all requirements I have and works like charm. I do not need my glue code any longer!

Comment: Could you use TestNG?  It allows ordering of tests, making it simpler for you to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: @manish: I had the same idea (switching to TestNG - but I did not find good examples for my requirements - yet. Maybe I am too dumb to use google :-) If you have good documentations for functional testing web services with TestNG it would be very kind of you to tell me about them ;-)

Comment: I think what you need the most is a way to order tests and to skip tests if any previous ones fail.  Ordering is simply about adding `priority` to `@Test`.  `@Test(priority = 1)` will run before `@Test(priority = 2)` and so on.  Skipping is about adding `dependsOnMethods` to `@Test`.  `@Test(priority = 1) public void first() {}`, `@Test(priority = 2, dependsOnMethod="first") public void second() {}` will ensure that `second` will be run only if `first` succeeds.  You may simply be able to skip using `priority` if you use just `dependsOnMethod`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Unit Test a servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137484/how-do-i-unit-test-a-servlet)

Comment: @Raedwald: IMHO it is not a duplicate. The initial question is quite differet and the solution will olso differ.

Comment: @manish: THX! I willtry that out. What about parallel testing different test classes?

Comment: The [official TestNG documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests) is quite comprehensive and covers all you need about running tests in parallel.

Comment: THX! Using TestNG from now on :-)